# how to count in rows in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a column that takes user names. How can I count the number of instances of a users name. For example I have 10 rows and in column username i want to count all names that show up multiple times. I would like to build a list of the top contributors to my database. So if username alex shows up 5 times and jeff shows up 3 and april shows up 2 times i will count this and from that I can build my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try GROUP BY:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS user_count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY user_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT USER_NAME, COUNT(USER_NAME) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY USER_NAME;
```

Comment: You rarely want to use COUNT(colname) - and you dont include the username in the result so its basically just random numbers returned by the querey

Comment: I thought the problem was about using "group by" not about adding the username in the select statement... i've updated my answer so you can see the number of results for every user.

Comment: Concerning COUNT(colname) as I don't know his data and as he might need to count for NULL usernames... I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a count of all the usernames then you just do the following SQL:

```
Select Count(*) from tablename
```

If you want to get just the count of unique usernames

```
Select Count(*) from tablename Group by username
```